# Numerical result out of range

Tags: c++, c, semaphore

I have a program that creates semaphore. But when i try to use SETALL, i get the error in errno as

> Numerical result out of range

```
if((temp_semid = semget(IPC_PRIVATE, 250, 0666 | IPC_CREAT)) != -1)
{    
  semun arg; 
  ushort array[100];
  memset(array,0, 100);
  arg.array = array;
  if(semctl(temp_semid, 0, SETALL, arg) == -1){ 
   std::cout << " failed to setall semaphore" << std::endl;
   std::cout << strerror(errno) << std::endl;
    break;
  }    
}
```

What is wrong?

Comment: I am unsure if `std::cout` use inteferes with `errno` but to be sure I would store the value of `errno` immediately after the call to `semtctl` to be certain of the correct `errno` value. Also, the `memset()` is not quite right: `memset(array, 0, 100 * sizeof(ushort));` or just `ushort array[100] = { 0 };`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked.

```
if((temp_semid = semget(IPC_PRIVATE, 250, 0666 | IPC_CREAT)) != -1)
{    
  semun arg; 
  ushort array[100] = { 0 };
  arg.array = array;
  if(semctl(temp_semid, 0, SETALL, arg) == -1){ 
   std::cout << " failed to setall semaphore" << std::endl;
   std::cout << strerror(errno) << std::endl;
    break;
  }    
}
```

i was using memset in the wrong way. thanks to hmjd for pointing that out.

Comment: Actually, the 0 also isn't necessary.  What you write is: initialize the array 'array' with as first element the ushort(int(0)), and all other elements zero-initialized. You can just write: 'ushort array[100] = {};'.  For completeness 'ushort array[100] = {1, 2, 3};' would assign 1, 2 and 3 to the first three elements, and all others zero.